# Create custom Country-State selection with React + Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

This question might sound stupid, please pardon my little knowledge. I saw a JSON data on country-region. I want to consume that JSON data by accessing the countries and region through Material UI Select Component. Basically, i want to create mine using MUI select Component.

How do i pass the Json Data to the select field of the Country, change the region based on the country

just like this library

`https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-country-region-selector`

**The reason why i don't want this is because it is very complex to add styles, and i don't want to have a different style since i'm using MUI.**

if the component is:
These components by default will use The MUI `<Select />`

```
<CountryComponent value={country's data from JSON} onChange={} />
<RegionComponent value={state data from JSON} country={based on country Selected} onChange={} />
```

Thank you!

Comment: Could you provide full or part of the JSON file?

Comment: This is the Repo: https://github.com/country-regions/country-region-data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this: https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-cache-q8l8n?file=/src/App.js.

I created a file `countries.js` and added two countries and two regions for both. They have the same schema as counties and regions in react-country-region-selector library.

The logic is simple: while you didn’t choose any country you can't choose any region. Both keeps in state.

Comment: Awesome... how can i access the selected data... it returns an object, but i need the value to store in the db

Comment: Should i just say country.countryName... to use it?

Comment: What value do you need? The names of the country and the region?

Comment: Yes sir.. exactly

Comment: You can get names in this way: `country.countryName` and `region.name` from the state

Comment: Does it solve your problem? Or I should update the code on codesandbox?

Comment: I updated, check it. Now country and region is the names

Comment: Cool... One last thing, please can you update the sandbox using Formik to get the values of both country and region